# I have a problem fetching data from relational table from mssql with JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jpa

I have a problem fetching data from relational tables with JPA. I believe that my problem is my use of annotations. Im kinda new to this and would love some guidance.

I've had some problem with this before and now that im on vacation I really want to learn 
Picture entity

```
@Entity
        @Table(name = "Picture")
        public class Picture {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        @NotNull
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "path")
        @NotNull

        private String path;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "portfolio_id", nullable = false)
        private Portfolio portfolio;

and getters, setters.
```

Portfolio entity

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "Portfolio")
        public class Portfolio {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        @NotNull
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "Address")
        @NotNull
        private String address;

        @Column(name = "Description")
        @NotNull
        private String description;

        @Column(name = "Service")
        @NotNull
        private String service;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "portfolio")
        private Set<Picture> pictures;
```

In Portfolio Table I have this object

```
id        address                 description         service
2         Köpenhamnsvägen 33B     some desc           Full-Staging
```

and in Picture table i Have this object

```
id        path                 portfolio_id
1         https://bild.se                 2
```

When I do a simple get request that fires repository.findAll I get this output:

[image: Nested object of get request]

It's like 5000 rows of this nested object. How come?

Best regards!

Comment: Sorry but JPA has absolutely nothing to do with converting your data to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a bidirectional mapping, so it comes to a recursion.
To solve this, just try to add @XmlTransient (JAX-B) or @JsonbTransient/@JsonIgnore (Jackson)
to one of the fields. This will make it 'invisible' in the JSON represantation of your backend/RESTful server.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "portfolio_id", nullable = false)
@XmlTransient/@JsonbTransient/@JsonIgnore (try all 3 annotations, since I dont know what implemantation of JAX-RS you are using
private Portfolio portfolio;
```

or you could do it for the Set:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "portfolio")
@XmlTransient/@JsonbTransient/@JsonIgnore //again: try them out, I don't know your implementation
private Set<Picture> pictures;
```

However doing it for both at the same time is not a good idea, since you won't see anything in the request as a result.

Comment: That worked great, thanks dude! Now my problem is that if i do a post with a portfolio object that contains an array that has two picture objects. Then it wont insert the pictures to db, only the portfolio.

Comment: Try adding `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to `Portfolio.pictures`. You might even want `CascadeType.ALL` if `Picture`s are *privately owned* by `Portfolio`s. See [this blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) for a detailed explanation